# Sort list of objects containing other objects by string C# Linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-standard-2.0

I want to add functionality to sort data, by getting the string of the sort column from the Angular frontend. Here follows a short scenario.

The database model of *ObjectA : Entity, IAggregateRoot*. *ObjectA* has simple elements like *Id* and *Name*, but also has an extra object *ObjectB*. *ObjectB* has simple elements like *Id* and *Name*, but also has an extra object *ObjectC*, which only has simple objects *Id* and *Name*.

```
ObjectA: {
    Id: Guid,
    Name: String,
    ObjectB: {
        Id: Guid,
        Name: String,
        ObjectC: {
            Id: Guid,
            Name: String,
        }
    }
}
```

The model that is given to the frontend is flattened with only important elements:

```
ObjectA: {
    Id: Guid,
    Name: String,
    ObjectBName: String,
    ObjectCName: String
}
```

Now, a list of *ObjectA* is displayed, and I want to add sorting on it. I receive the element name (string) from the frontend to sort on, e.g. *id*. This sort is easily done in the backend by a Linq query like:

```
return objectAList.OrderBy(x => GetPropertyToSort(x, orderByString));
```

With the function *GetPropertyToSort()*:

```
private string GetPropertyToSort(object obj, string orderBy)
    {
        var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(char.ToUpper(orderBy[0]) + orderBy.Substring(1));
        var propValue = prop.GetValue(obj)?.ToString();
        return propValue;
    }
```

But how can sorting by another object element, e.g. *objectCName*, be achieved by receiving only the flattened string value (which is actually the element *ObjectA.ObjectB.ObjectC.Name*)?

Comment: Is `orderByString == "ObjectCName"` or `orderByString == "ObjectA.ObjectB.ObjectC.Name"`? (If it's the former, and the ordered list is the flattened one, you can still use `GetPropertyToSort`)